# Яндекс метрика. Logs API. Получить информацию, на какие страницы заходил пользователь

Tags: yandex-metrika-api

Я использую Яндекс Метрику в своём сервисе. При помощи Logs API мне нужно посмотреть, на какие страницы переходил пользователь. Чтобы идентифицировать пользователя в системе, в качестве параметров я передаю в Яндекс Метрику userId. Если сгенерировать отчёт в Logs API с `source = hits` и `fields = ym:pv:URL,ym:pv:parsedParamsKey1`, а потом получить этот отчёт, то для столбца `ym:pv:parsedParamsKey1` я получу только массив параметров (в моём случае - `['userId']`), но я не получаю значение этого параметра. Есть ли возможность как-то получить значение параметра в Logs API?